# What are the constraints on the type of `self`?

Tags: rust

In the Rust Book, there's an [example implementing the *state pattern*](https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch17-03-oo-design-patterns.html#requesting-a-review-of-the-post-changes-its-state) containing the following `impl` block,

```rust
impl State for Draft {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        Box::new(PendingReview {})
    }
}
```

Up until this point, the book has only used `Self`, `&Self` or `&mut Self` as the type of `self`, which led me to believe that these were the only types allowed. How is `Box<Self>` allowed here when the `impl` block is being defined on `Draft`, not `Box<Draft>`? Given a type `MyType<T>`, can the type of `self` for methods defined on `Draft` be `fn foo(self: MyType<Draft>)`? Is `Box` special in some way?